# Is it possible to add a query parameter to Lookup Page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Following url takes away to a lookup page that is returning all contact records.

https://c.cs7.visual.force.com/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkfm=j_id0:j_id2&lknm=j_id0:j_id2:j_id30:who&lktp=003&lksrch=

I want to restrict returned contact records in lookup page. Is there a query parameter like:

```
lkqry=SELECT FirstName FROM Contact WHERE id='012345678912345'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to customise the standard Lookup Popup page.

Instead, you will have to create your own. It is not too difficult to create but it takes some time with testing and all that.

Jeff Douglas has a great tutorial that I have used.

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/